# How many staples to fasten 6/3 cable to studs?

Tags: electrical

I installed a 14-50 outlet in my garage with NM-B 6/3 cable and now I'm ready to patch up the holes in the drywall and I was wondering if I should fasten the cable to the studs. I looked at NEC 300.19 and table 300.19(A). The cable goes from the breaker panel (2nd story) to the garage (1st floor) like this: 6 ft from the breaker panel to the floor, 1 foot between the floor joist to the top plate garage wall, then 8 ft (thru a fire block) to the outlet below. If I read the NEC right, I only need one staple below the top plate and another between the breaker panel and the floor. Am'I right?

Thanks

Comment: Pictures would be helpful. If the holes in the wall are small enough, you'd probably get away with no staples. In the attic though you'd need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You'll need to staple it down every 4.5', and within 12" of the boxes

This support requirement comes from NEC 334.30:

> **334.30 Securing and Supporting.** Nonmetallic-sheathed cable
>   shall be supported and secured by staples; cable ties listed and
>   identified for securement and support; or straps, hangers, or
>   similar fittings designed and installed so as not to damage the
>   cable, at intervals not exceeding 1.4 m (4½ ft) and within
>   300 mm (12 in.) of every cable entry into enclosures such as
>   outlet boxes, junction boxes, cabinets, or fittings. Flat cables
>   shall not be stapled on edge.